# How can I know amount cap for cards?

Tags: gwent

I'm pretty new to Gwent and decided to build a deck around specific bronze card. To my surprise I cannot have more than 3 copies of that card (I crafted all 3 of them). I've checked my other cards, and noticed that I have:

- One bronze unit card with 3 copies cap;
- One bronze special card with 3 copies cap;
- One bronze special card with unknown cap - I've already have 5 of them and can craft more.

How can I know maximum possible amount of any card before hitting the cap?

I play on PS4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about caps in the deck? The answer to that is: Silvers/Golds only get one copy. You can have 6 silvers total. 4 Golds total. 3 per Bronze card.

If you're talking about limits on the number of cards in your collection, the game will not allow you to craft more than 3, because that's the limit on repeat cards. Your collection will go up by 1 if you unlock that card in a certain way, allowing you redeem extra cards for currency.

Type of version (PC vs Console) does not matter, all Gwent is played the same.